# Enumerate array of Any objects in swift

Tags: swift

I want to enumerate my array of `Any` objects, with access to index of element. However, swift throw an error:

> Type '() -> EnumeratedSequence<[Any]>' does not conform to protocol 'Sequence'`

My code is:

```
var arrValues : [Any]!

for (index, ob) in arrValues.enumerated() {
    print("\(index): '\(ob)'")
}
```

How to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to follow correct syntax, I thought you are doing like below image,

[image]

But, the actual code is,

```
for (index, ob) in arrValues.enumerated(){
//.....
}
```

Also, you need  a `Optional var` for check it has value or not.

```
    var arrValues : [Any]?

    if arrValues?.count != nil{
        for (index, ob) in (arrValues?.enumerated())! {

            print("\(index): '\(ob)'")
        }
    }else{
        print("Array is Empty")
    }
```

**Output**:

Click [here](http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/5971dae4ef0a7c6ae6ad4b87) to see output.

Answer (score 1):

This is the way you go

```
    var arrValues = [Any]()
    for var i in 0..<arrValues.count {

        print("\(i): '\(arrValues[i])'")
    }
```

This will also work

```
var arrValues = [Any]()
for (index, ob) in arrValues.enumerated() {
    print("\(index): '\(ob)'")
}
```

Comment: Note the difference that you have defined arrValues as implicitly unwrapped optional. Please accept the answer if it works for you.

Comment: You don't need to create the range `0 ..< arrValues.count` manually. You can just use the `indices` property of your collection: `for i in arrValues.indices`. Also, why are you manually incrementing i? Swift will do that automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are declaring an array without creating its instance.

You can use below snippet:

```
var arrValues = [Any]()

for (index, ob) in arrValues.enumerated() {
    print("\(index): '\(ob)'")
}
```